# Prós e contras de uma aplicação web 100% HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web-service, aplicação-web, single-page-application

Estou seriamente pensando de desenvolver uma aplicação web, utilizando somente HTML/JavaScript no *client-side* para ganho de desempenho e pelo qual, toda e qualquer comunicação necessária com o servidor seja feita através de requisições a um WebService (lá sim, conterá minha regra de negócios).

Gostaria que citassem (tecnicamente) os prós e contras desta técnica.

Comment: Esse tipo de pergunta vai ter muita resposta baseada em opiniões, mas pode existir uma parte técnica mais profunda, caso você deixe a pergunta um pouco mais "fechada" a questões técnicas, tente dar uma melhorada no texto da pergunta. (:

Comment: Iago, sugiro a mudança do título. Não sei se "Aplicação 100% HTML/Javascript" passa a ideia correta. Talvez ficasse melhor: "Prós e Contras de uma Aplicação de Página Única (Single Page Application)".

Comment: Mais uma coisa: reabri a questão porque depois da edição ela ficou melhor. É possível responder objetivamente prós e contras desta técnica. As respostas abaixo soam estranho por começarem com "No meu ponto de vista" e "Na minha opinião", o que ocorreu porque a pergunta não estava tão bem formulada, mas ainda assim acrescentaram algumas informações pertinentes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prós :

- WebDesigners tem grande facilidade com essa arquitetura.
- Sua aplicação é facilmente integrada com outros sistemas. Pois assim você obrigatoriamente tem que criar uma API para conectar com seu frontend. Logo é possível criar múltiplos frontends,
- Facilidade para testes unitários.

Contras :

- Duplicidade de Validações. Mais do que nunca, você precisa desenvolver validações do lado do servidor e do lado do cliente. Nunca confie em uma validação que está apenas do lado do cliente.
- Cuidado com frameworks Javascript que ainda estão em estágio de amadurecimento, podem gerar retrabalho.

Answer (score 14):

Obviamente todos os prós e contras dependem não só da técnica utilizada, mas também da implementação real.

## Prós

- Melhor experiência do usuário respondendo mais rápido e sem quebras no fluxo da informação. O usuário não vê o mecanismo funcionando.
- Redução de carga do servidor que não precisa "renderizar" as páginas, só trabalha com os dados.
- Menor volume de dados trafegados (na maioria dos casos não muita diferença). Costuma haver um ganho perceptível de performance.
- Há um desacoplamento maior entre o que está no servidor e o cliente. Dá mais liberdade ao *designer*. Eventualmente pode aumentar a segurança.

## Contras

- Obviamente a exigência do JavaScript (ou outra linguagem) funcionando corretamente.
- Problemas com SEO (não, o fato do Google interpretar JS, não resolveu o problema).
- É comum ter mais brechas de segurança expondo coisas que não deveria (XSS principalmente). A exposição pode causar outros problemas também.
- Uma aplicação dessas rodando muito tempo no navegador pode ser devoradora de recursos, principalmente se houver vazamento de recursos, o que é comum.
- Há casos que precisa duplicar código do servidor no cliente.
- A carga inicial pode ser maior e causar frustração (UX ruim).
- Não é simples fazer corretamente.

Existem algumas coisas que as pessoas reclamam que não são problemas mais.

Obviamente posso ter esquecido alguma coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Havia cometido um equívoco de interpretação da pergunta, por isso resolvi reestruturar minha resposta. Espero que ajude na solução de sua dúvida.

Prós:

1. Centralização do acesso à fonte de dados o que facilita à analise de uso, performance.
2. Fácil manutenção/atualização do da parte pública da aplicação
3. Compartilhamento de código

Contras:

1. Sobrecarga de processamento
2. Arquitetura bloqueante, uma vez que um processamento que utiliza recursos compartilhados espera um processo dependente finalizar antes de inicializar outro.
3. Dificuldade para equiparar o comportamento visual em todas as plataformas e dispositivos.
4. Alto acoplamento/dependência à internet.

Um Abraço.

Vinicius

Comment: Olá, Vinicius. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Eu sei que o título da pergunta fala de HTML e JavaScript, mas a questão na verdade está pedindo os prós e contras de se fazer um sistema assíncrono, assim como é o Gmail e outras aplicações que não atualizam a página, acessando todas as informações via web services.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz. Sou novo por aqui, e estou com dificuldades pra aprender a utilizar esta plataforma. Quando iniciei minha carreira, tive grande ajuda desta comunidade, e gostaria de retribuir à esta ajuda, contribuindo com aqueles que estão passando pelo que passei, Por isso qualquer dica(links , artigos) será bem vinda para aprender a gerar conteúdos de qualidade. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

No meu ponto de vista essa é a melhor maneira de se trabalhar na Web, pois a maioria dos outros modelos de trabalho, trafegam HTML do server pro client e isso não faz muito sentido. Dessa forma você tem um ganho de performance, trafegando somente dados necessários.

Trabalhando dessa forma você pode aproveitar seu código de front e empacotar ele com phonegap, assim criar web apps sem tem que programar novamente.

Para questão de SEO como o Afonso sitou existem ferramentas ou modos de trabalho que te ajudam nisso. Por exemplo caso você use Angularjs que é algo que realmente complica o SEO, você pode utilizar o Prerender (https://prerender.io/), que ajuda você no SEO.

Eu particularmente não vejo contras em trabalhar dessa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Prós:

- Sem dependência do Framework ou biblioteca;
- Fácil manutenção;
- Código simples;
- Absorção maior do conhecimento característico sobre a linguagem.

Contras:

- Códigos verbosos
- Aumento na estrutura da aplicação
- Reinventar a roda;
- Retrabalho se não for bem estruturado.