# Por que usar o AngularJS?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Eu tenho pesquisado bastante, mas não consigo entender o porquê de usar o AngularJS, sendo que utilizo paginas `.php` então os retornos do banco, CRUD e etc. Eu trato diretamente nas paginas `.php`, listas de registros do banco, inserção e essas coisas.

Onde e como o AngularJS pode me ajudar? Em que aplicações as pessoas mais usam?

Comment: Por que tá na moda, hehehe

Comment: Não tenho experiência com angular, mas eu ACHO que ele seja mais indicado quando você trabalha com API. Onde tudo que o back end faz é disponibilizar dados brutos (JSON).

Comment: Você pode dividir responsabilidades com AngularJS, o Front e Back-end são independentes. Você pode utilizar o mesmo back-end que no caso será uma API REST pra outros fins, como mobile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Há muita opinião sobre o assunto, resolvi responder para tentar uma resposta que não caia muito nisto, por isso ela não é muito extensiva. Não ficarei afirmando sobre o que há controvérsias se é uma vantagem mesmo ou não.

O principal motivo das pessoas usarem AngularJS (ou Angular que é o que todo mundo usa hoje em dia) quando resolvem trabalhar com [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Ou seja, quando se produz uma aplicação baseada em tecnologia web onde uma única página (não é tão rígido assim) faz todas as operações.

Então lembre-se que o cliente (a página) acaba trabalhando de forma independente e toda renderização da visualização ocorre no navegador (ou eventualmente outro *host* do cliente). Em geral o acesso ao servidor é feito através de um acesso que forneça uma API ao invés de páginas pré-renderizadas lá (ainda que isto possa ocorrer também em algumas situações, pelo menos o primeiro acesso costuma mandar a página-aplicação).

Outro motivo já foi dito em comentário: moda. Muitos não percebem que esse tipo de aplicação [estraga o tão perseguido SEO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77808/101). E que existem [outras desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102637/101) em optar por isso. Mas moda tem a ver com as pessoas usarem porque os outros estarem usando. Pode ser que algumas pessoas saibam porque estão usando, as outras usam porque elas não sabem, mas leem algum blog e acham que tem o mesmo problema, ela só quer fazer o mesmo na esperança que aquilo lhe ajude.

Claro que há vantagens também, que se for uma **aplicação** de fato, e não um website, pode fazer sentido o seu uso para facilitar certas operações, tais como:

- manipulação do DOM (de forma mais ampla que o jQuery, que por sinal nem faz sentido mais)
- fazer *data binding*
- adotar o MVC ou MVVM de forma "simples"
- usar um mecanismo de *templating*
- entre outras operações comuns feitas de forma correta pronta para uso.

Em tese pode ser usado para qualquer coisa, até mesmo *websites* se puder conviver com as dificuldades, mas a maioria adota sem ter consciência das dificuldades neste caso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é SPA e no que se diferencia de uma página não SPA?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212952/66203)

Answer (score 10):

O texto abaixo é o resultado de um recente período de imersão nesse mundo de Angular para aprendizado. Peço que a comunidade me auxilie a melhorar meu entendimento caso exista algo incorreto ou ausente.

O AngularJS é um framework para desenvolvimento de Single Page Applications (SPA).

Um Single Page Application é, de forma simples, uma aplicação web composta de uma única página. Todos os assets necessário (HTML, CSS e JS) são carregados em um único load (o inicial) e os componentes da página construidos dinamicamente utilizando JS de acordo com as ações do usuário.

A maior vantagem de um SPA é que a página torna-se muito mais responsiva e ágil, tornando a experiência mais próxima de uma aplicação desktop. Na necessidade da criação de uma página que exija extrema responsividade, pode ser o caso para um SPA.

As aplicações de um SPA são as mais variadas e, principalmente, com a grande quantidade de frameworks que utilizam este conceito (AngularJS, React, EmberJS, Meteor ...) a tendência é que cada vez mais páginas neste modelo surjam.

Certamente você já visitou alguma página que funciona neste formato como a página do [Angular2](https://angular.io/), a do [Protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) ou o próprio Gmail. Ao clicar nos links disponíveis na página, não há outro load: os componentes são atualizados na mesma página. Qualquer dado adicional necessário é obtido utilizando AJAX.

Diferente do PHP onde sua lógica está sendo executada do lado do servidor um SPA usa JS de forma pesada, ou seja, demanda mais processamento da estação do usuário (para processar o JS) e comunica-se com um Back-End conforme necessário.

Um bom 'efeito colateral' de um SPA, na minha opinião, é desacoplamento da lógica de Front-End e Back-End. Analise algum código Angular e você verá que as tarefas de renderização de páginas estarão no Front End.

As demais tarefas referentes à persistência (crud, como você citou), computações pesadas de dados e outros estarão em uma segunda aplicação que será o Back-End, geralmente, oferecendo uma API Rest para consumo dos dados.

Outras vantagens geralmente citadas são:

- O Back-End não precisar guardar o estado da navegação do usuário, ficando isto à encargo do Front-End, onde geralmente a tarefa é feito utilizando recursos locais da estação do usuário (usando Web Storage, por exemplo)
- Possibilidade de uma aplicação funcionar Offline, uma vez que após o download dos assets para a estação do usuário a aplicação precisará de um Back-End apenas para sincronizar dados e outras operações (Nota: isto traz algumas implicações que estão fora do âmbito desta resposta)

Note que isto não é uma solução universal e sim um 'caso'. Muitos estão construindo sites neste modelo por, como você disse, moda.

Comment: Então seria vantajoso, sempre que possível, utilizar um SPA no desenvolvimento de um sistema? Ate criei um tópico sobre o assunto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154739/web-moderna-spa-rest?noredirect=1#comment319468_154739

Comment: Uma sugestão de leitura para te ajudar na decisão de usar um SPA ou não é o tópico http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862054/single-page-application-advantages-and-disadvantages, e a leitura deste artigo (http://adamsilver.io/articles/the-disadvantages-of-single-page-applications/). Note que algumas coisas mudaram de 2014 para cá mas os pontos ainda são relevantes. Em minha opinião, SPAs brilham em aplicações que dependam fortemente de dados externos (de um backend) às custas de um front end com complexidade elevada.