# Web Moderna: SPA/REST

Tags: aplicação-web, rest, single-page-application

Falando na web moderna, temos conceitos novos como SPA/Rest e mantenho algumas dúvidas.

O correto ao ingressar na web é focar/estudar essas conceitos? Já que surgiram como melhoria de alguns conceitos antigos.

É viável sempre ou quando poder utilizar SPA/Rest? Sei que com uma rest em mãos posso utilizar ela para servir várias outras aplicações, como apps mobile, fora a estabilidade e etc.

Em questão de segurança, é seguro utilizar uma SPA? Em uma palestra sobre SPA, que a validação se foca no front, porem eu Nao deixaria de fazer a validação no servidor, acho que Nao tem nem sentido fazer isso.

Falo em sistemas de todos os contextos, tamanhos, objetivos e etc.

Sei que muitas dessas coisas nao são tão novas assim, estando presentes na web a bastante tempo, porem ainda são propostos muitos conceitos "antigos".

Comment: Validação client-side faz sentido pra diminuir a carga do servidor e para tornar a experiência do usuário mais ágil (validação client-side é sempre mais rápida). Claro que não substitui a validação no servidor, mas validar instantaneamente melhora a experiência do usuário sem onerar o servidor.

Comment: Então no caso poderia continuar usando nós dois lados, mas com um adiantamento do cliente, apesar que acho inseguro, por ser possível manipular o javascript.

Comment: Não é inseguro porque a validação final é no servidor.

Comment: Foi mal, acabei me expressando errado, eu quis dizer que continuaria achando inseguro se for totalmente no cliente e não no servidor. Se for nós dois lado, eu concordo.

Answer (score 3):

**O correto ao ingressar na web é focar/estudar esses conceitos?**

Sim. É sempre bom estar atualizado com novas tecnologias. **SPA** significa *Single Page Application*, é um novo modelo de desenvolvimento de aplicações Web e mobile que vem ganhando destaque em grandes empresas como Microsoft, Google, Twitter, Facebook, etc. Ele basicamente significa codificar menos no `server-side` e mais no `client-side`. Ou seja, a aplicação estará contida toda ou quase toda no cliente (dentro do navegador Web). É praticamente uma aplicação Desktop rodando sob o navegador.

**É viável sempre ou quando poder utilizar SPA/Rest?**

Tudo tem vantagens e desvantagens.

- **Vantagem:**

  - Balanceamento da responsabilidade da execução entre cliente e servidor
  - Menos código do servidor, e mais responsabilidade no cliente;
  - Melhorar a experiência ao usuário (UX) criando interface com usabilidade moderna e de fácil entendimento do usuário;
  - Menor consumo de banda, pois as cargas de dados são feitas por demanda e por `AJAX`.
- **Desvantagem**

  - Muito código `JavaScript` para gerenciar no navegador, o carregamento da página inicial pode ser muito lenta (uma vez que você tem que carregar e executar uma tonelada de JS). Se você usar um servidor web `JavaScript` como `Node.js`, você pode resolver parcialmente as duas últimas questões, tornando o `server-side` mesma página.

**Em questão de segurança, é seguro utilizar uma SPA?**

De acordo com esse [site](https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-single-page-app-problem), não. Por que estes tipos de aplicações são chamadas de "clientes não confiáveis", já que o nosso código do lado do servidor não tem controle sobre o ambiente em que executar. Mesmo aplicações web regulares têm esses problemas. As pessoas podem facilmente alterar ou injetar código `JavaScript` em uma página através do console desenvolvedor. Aplicativos móveis, tais como aqueles no Android e iOS, pode ser compilado e inspecionados. Como tal, você não gostaria de incorporar informações sensíveis, como chaves secretas ou senhas nestes tipos de clientes.

Referências:

- [Não exponha seu REST](https://www.infoq.com/br/news/2013/09/nao-exponha-seu-rest)
- [O que é SPA](http://andremenegassi.com.br/blog/index.php/spa-single-page-application-e-restrestful-o-que-e/)
- [What is SPA](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-SPA-single-page-application-over-a-normal-web-application)
- [ASP.NET - Single-Page Applications: Build Modern, Responsive Web Apps with ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx)
- [Maravilhas da Web Moderna](http://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/single-page-applications-e-outras-maravilhas-da-web-moderna/?trace=1519021197)

Comment: Não estou dizendo que sua resposta esta errada, essa parte ''teórica'' eu já sabia, ate alguns dos sites que deu de referencia eu havia entrado, mas o que se matem são as duvidas que coloquei aqui na pergunta.

Comment: @Marcial, editei a resposta enfatizando suas perguntas.

Comment: foi mal se caso anteriormente eu pareci "arrogante" ou algo parecido, e acabei não pedindo se pudesse complementar com educação, já irei ler novamente, grato. @Taisbevalle

Comment: @Marcial, não tem problema, achei que você queria saber um pouco da teoria também, com o seu comentário pude melhorar a resposta =)

Comment: É realmente, vai depender da situação e do que o cliente deseja, requisitos, se o foco é mais na usabilidade, arquitetura disponível e etc. Eu venho do back, e não sou fan da sintaxe do javascript(typescript *-*), mas como não posso contar com alguém como front, vou ter que me tornar "full-stack" ou pelo menos quase isso kkk'. Sobre Rest, mesmo que não tenha comentado, seguindo a mesma situação das SPA, não se encaixando em todas situações, é de grande relevância poder servir varias aplicações e ate distribuir seus serviços e etc, Dês de já, obrigado @Taisbeballe

Comment: @Marcial, de nada =)