# ASP.NET WebForms, MVC ou WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api

Primeiramente gostaria de ressaltar que meus conhecimentos em desenvolvimento web é bem pequeno, então minha pergunta será direcionada em o que usar e não como usar, pois o objetivo é estudar primeiro para depois desenvolver.

Preciso criar uma aplicação web para abertura de chamados, o cliente deverá ver uma página simples onde irá descrever dúvidas, reclamações, etc. e nessa mesma página poderá anexar documentos, imagens, etc.

Essa mesma aplicação deverá conter um chat, para que os clientes possam se comunicar diretamente com o pessoal do suporte e obter maiores esclarecimentos quanto aos chamados já abertos.

Ao criar um novo projeto web no Visual Studio 2013, me deparei com os *templates* (Web Forms, MVC e WEB API, dentre outros). Gostaria de obter de vocês um direcionamento, como, por onde devo começar a estudar para esboçar uma aplicação conforme mencionado acima.

Abaixo, alguns critérios que acho importante mencionar para a possível decisão do que usar:

- Preciso usar ASP.NET, C# e Visual Studio 2013.
- Já possuo uma base de dados SQL Server (atualmente usada para a aplicação desktop) que contém todas as informações que serão utilizadas.
- Na base de dados que já possuo, já tenho uma tabela com os usuários e senhas que os mesmos deverão utilizar para efetuar login.

Obs: Minha intenção mesmo é saber de vocês que já desenvolvem para a web, o que utilizar e por onde começar, com foco em estudar para obter conhecimento para iniciar o projeto.

Comment: para quem esta começando use ASP.NET MVC inicialmente depois aprenda WebApi. O Webforms não recebera mais atualizações so vale pena aprender se você vai trabalhar em empresas que usam sistema legados nessa tecnologia , para seu caso mvc atende tudo que você quer.

Comment: Bem, **Web Forms** e **MVC** são padrões de desenvolvimento de sites. Neste caso sugiro você usar o **MVC**, pois **Web Forms** é obsoleto hoje em dia para novos projetos. Já **WebApi** é um *framework*  para desenvolvimento de serviços `Rest`. São coisas distintas.. .como @EduardoSampaio comentou, primeiro estude e entenda bem o **MVC** depois vá para **Web Api**

Comment: Obrigado @EduardoSampaio, vou iniciar meus estudos em MVC, caso tenha algum curso on-line ou livro pra indicar, agradeço!

Comment: Obrigado @RicardoPontual

Comment: eu aprendi bastante coisa no canal do Cleyton ferrari https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbA_JZJtKaY

Comment: Fuja de vídeo aulas a não ser que seja algo oficial ou seja de alguém com reconhecimento forte na comunidade (quase ninguém têm). Isto ocorre com outros tipos de material, mas alguns tem um filtro maior. Video aula qualquer pode fazer. E fuja mais + de coisas antigas (+ atrapalha que ajuda). Infelizmente é um drama achar material bom p/ estudar. Todo mundo acha que achou e quem faz acha que fez algo bom. A realidade é bem diferente. Isto ocorre por causa do https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect. Pode começar porque aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc/info

Comment: Obrigado @bigown

Comment: @PauloBalbino A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 5):

É uma pena saber que está restrito ao Visual Studio 2013. Se for custo, tem versões gratuitas do VS moderno e quase sompleto.

WebForms é uma tecnologia considerada praticamente legada e esquisita. Algumas pessoas acham mais fácil, mas tem pouco espaço no cenário web atual. Não o descarte, mas tem muitos motivos para não começar algo novo com ele, e nem sei se no seu caso existe algum para usá-lo.

Já que não pode usar ASP.NET Core que é o mais moderno e me parece que interessa fazer uma aplicação completa e não apenas uma API, o caminho parece ser o ASP.NET MVC.

Se precisar fornecer uma API para outros programadores se comunicarem com seu sistema diretamente sem a interação do usuário diretamente com seu sistema, aí terá que usar o ASP.NET WebAPI também (no ASP.NET Core é uma coisa só).

Mais recentemente algumas pessoas estão optando por fazer o máximo possível no cliente, fazem as chamadas [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), muitas vezes com [AngularJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123913/101). Aí muito provavelmente usuária só o ASP.NET WebAPI já que o MVC é usado para o servidor gerar as páginas sob demanda. Com o uso de SPA o cliente carrega uma só pagina e vai solicitando apenas dados ao servidor.

As informações para tomar a decisão estão aí. Qual é o mais adequado para você só você mesmo pode responder.